Set Shader Graph out position in clip space
Is it possible to set the output vertex position in a space other than object space?


Are you using URP or HDRP?

@DMGregory URP!

I think you can use the position node to get the world space position of the object the shader was applied to. https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@7.1/manual/Position-Node.html.    There is also a transform node: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@7.1/manual/Transform-Node.html

@CheckerT sure I can but will it be optimized?
I mean this seems sily, i could end up doing transformations back and forward((

As CheckerT suggests, I'd solve this with a Transform node.
Here's an example that does the following:

Take the UV coordinates of a quad as input.
Remap the x & y from the 0-1 range to a desired rectangle in clip space (-1 to 1). Note that the y coordinate is inverted (-1 is the top of the screen).
Compose this into a 4-vector with w = 1 (so the perspective divide is a no-op and can be ignored), and whatever z value you want to use for depth comparisons.
Multiply this by the inverse projection matrix to go from clip space into view space.
Use a Transform node to go from View to Object space.


This does add some extra vector-matrix multiplications to the shader, but it's not dire.
There may be a way to author your own shader root nodes in the scriptable render pipeline, so make a vertex node that works in clip space by default, but I have not investigated that yet.

Nice try @DMGregory, but for now i had to do the same thing you did. However this is not the answer(((
It would be so nice if you will post something like: here is a way to hack a root node!

According to the latest discussion on the topic I've found, custom master nodes are currently not supported and not on the roadmap, though the thread does have some leads on how you can hack something in if you're willing to get deep into the weeds. It's unfortunately more complex than I'll have time to do on your behalf for free.
